# Highcharts fill bar background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

Hi guys I have a highcharts graph that is a stacked bar and I am trying to give my chart the effect that it is being filled, almost like a thermometer. Currently when the chart draws the red and gray bars push everything to the right. Is there a way that I can set the gray bar so that it shows right away on page load, and then the red bar fills into the gray bar? Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/jimbob25/L974T/

```
 series: [{
        name: 'null',
        data: [5, 69, 86, 75, 48],
        borderRadius: 5,
        color: "gray"
    }, {
        name: 'Values',
        data: [95, 31, 14, 25, 62],
        color: "red",
        borderRadius: 5
    }]
```

Update, I would like it to look like the first bar in the following link
http://jsfiddle.net/L974T/3/

You can see that the first bar is grey, i can make the rest gray and it would be fine, but the bars would not scale based off of resolution

Comment: are you looking something like this http://jsfiddle.net/L974T/2/

Comment: I think they are after something like http://jsfiddle.net/7CFP2/, but with the background of each bar show grey from 0 to 100 before the animation starts. This would give the effect of the bar filling up.

Comment: IN general, can you attach mockup how it should looks like?

Comment: This is what I would like it to look like, do you see how the first bar has the grey background filled? I can draw renderer.rects to do this for me, but unfortunately they do not scale based off of the resolution.

http://jsfiddle.net/L974T/3/

Comment: Have you tried to use additional plugin http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/5/Rounded-Corners ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

- add one more series, with different stack (as background) - animation for that series should be disabled (duplicated of gray one)
- change color for right-hand series to transparent

And here is working code: http://jsfiddle.net/L974T/4/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'null',
        data: [5, 69, 86, 75, 48],
        borderWidth: 0,
        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
    }, {
        name: 'null',
        data: [5, 69, 86, 75, 48],
        borderWidth: 0,
        stack: 1,
        animation: false,
        color: "gray"
    }, {
        name: 'Values',
        data: [95, 31, 14, 25, 62],
        color: "red",
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderRadius: 5
    }]
```

Comment: This solves the problem visually, but the gray area will possible to tab onto, and mouse over, and also will be read aloud by screen readers for blind users, so it is not a very nice solution. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Four years ago that was perfect solution.. now you can simply go to docs and use [bullet-chart](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/bullet-chart). There is also the best solution: use [Renderer](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/freeform-drawing) and render rectangles on your own (and/or whatever you need).